# Div doesn´t show background color after float:left

Tags: html, css

I need to show two `<div>`s next to each other and with different backgrounds.

Unfortunately, the `background-color` of the second `<div>` is ignored. I have read some posts and people suggest to add `clear:both;`. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Is there any way how to get a `background-color` for `.div2`?

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
    width:382px;
    padding:0 5px 10px 10px;
}
.div2 {
    margin-top:10px;
    width:374px;
    background:red;
    padding:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2">DIV2</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok  think i understood your problem. You want the element's next to each other.

Here is a CSS for this:

```
.div1 {  
    float:left;
    background:blue;
    width:382px;
    padding:0 5px 10px 10px;

}
.div2 {
    /* div1 will follow this */
    margin-top:10px;
    /* width of div1 + it's paddings */
    margin-left:397px; 
    width:374px;
    background:red;
    padding:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

And here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rvuyH/2/

Answer (score 0):

just add float:left for div2 css like below to display both divs next to each other with background color

```
.div2{margin-top:10px;width:374px;float:left;background:green;padding:0 10px 10px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the code given by @user3401335

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tXfZ5/4/). Please check it out

HTML:

```
 <div class="div1">DIV1</div> 
 <div class="div2">DIV2</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
   margin-top:10px;
   float:left;
   background:blue;
   width:50%;
   padding:0 5px 10px 10px;
 }
.div2 {
   margin-top:10px;
   width:45%;
   background:red;
   padding:0 10px 10px 0;
   float:left;
}
```